# Can not find cout uint_32 and other things after set the project to be 32-bit

Tags: c++, cmake

Here is my code, it correct without **CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-m32"**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    void *startPos;
    cout << startPos << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

It says `Use of undeclared identifier 'cout'`

Here is my Cmakelist

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(test)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-m32")

include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)

add_executable(test src/test.cpp)
```

I'm using wsl2 ubuntu20.04

gcc version 9.3.0 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04)

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/91909/trouble-compiling-a-32-bit-binary-on-a-64-bit-machine does this solve your problem?

Comment: I see what I missed. But it's not working after installed gcc-multilib. `/usr/include/c++/9/iostream:38:10: fatal error: bits/c++config.h: No such file or directory`

Comment: It was silly of me to forget g++-multilib. It works fine now.

Comment: However Clion has a problem. It says`Unknown type name 'uint16_t'` and `Use of undeclared identifier 'malloc'`. But it's able to compile and run.